# Error while compiling for Flutter Desktop

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

unable to compile my application for windows desktop.

`Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.1246]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\CREATIVE'S DEV\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>flutter run -d windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/Comm
onExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (me
ssage):
The C++ compiler

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/
```

bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/CREATIVE'S DEV/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app/build/windows/CMake
```

Files/CMakeTmp

```
Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuil
```

d/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_4a34b.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:Visual
StudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+b89cb5fde pour .NET Fram
ework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microso
```

ft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5677,7): error MSB4023: Impossible d'évaluer la métadonnée d
'élément "%(FullPath)". Impossible d'appliquer la métadonnée d'élément "%(FullPath)" au chemi
n d'accès "@(_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath->'C:\Users\CREATIVE'S DEV\AndroidStudioProjects\fl
utter_app\build\windows\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug%(Filename)%(Extension)')". Caractères non
conformes dans le chemin d'accès. [C:\Users\CREATIVE'S DEV\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app
build\windows\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_4a34b.vcxproj]

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)

Building Windows application...
Exception: Unable to generate build files
`

Comment: I renamed CREATIVE'S DEV by removing the space and '

Answer (score 0):

> Caractères non conformes dans le chemin d'accès.

Try moving your project to a path that doesn't have a `'` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing flutter via snap

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

then do that and it's good

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

if you installed `360safe`[image],you can try uninstall it, and run `flutter clean`, delete `window` folder, run `flutter create .` to fix it.